# How to compare data contained and retrieved from entry widgets with data retrieved from an SQL database in python?

Tags: python

I have created a login interface as part of an application I am creating. I derive the contents of username and password entries on this interface, and compare them Usernames and passwords stored in an SQL database in python.

However each time I test the program by entering a username and password to the login interface, that exists in the SQL database I created, the program displays an error message (this error message should only be displayed when the username and password contained in the username and password entries do not exist in the SQL database).

I have tried printing the contents of the username and password entries to ensure they contain valid data/ that they are not empty

I have tried printing the records in the database I created to ensure that their is valid data contained in it/ that it is not empty.

I have tried putting the contents of the username and password entry widgets into variables in python, and then I compared the data stored in these variables, with the usernames and passwords stored in the database I created.

I have tried removing the punctuation from list variables storing usernames and passwords from the SQL database, and then I tried to identify whether the username and password entered in the entry widgets on the login interface were in these username and password list variables I created. I thought that this could be the reason why the program was raising an error.

```
def UserDetailsValidator():

# stores usernames in UserDetails table of program's database
Usernames = []

# stores passwords in UserDetails table of program's database
Passwords = []

UserDetails = []

# retreives all usernames in Users database
for username in c.execute('SELECT Username FROM tblUserDetails'):
        Usernames.append(username)
# retrieves all passwords in Users database
for password in c.execute('SELECT Password FROM tblUserDetails'):
    Passwords.append(password)

##    # creates set of all possible punctuation marks
##    PunctuationMarks = set(string.punctuation)
##
##    # makes new username and passwords list
##    PunctuationFreeUsernames = ''.join(character for character in Usernames if character not in PunctuationMarks)
##    print(PunctuationFreeUsernames)

# checks if the username entered is in the Users table of the program's database
for username in range(len(Usernames)):
    if UsernameEntry.get() == username:
        break
    else:
        # displays an error message if the password the user enters is not in the Users table
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("","Your username has not been recognised, please try again")

# checks if the password entered is in the Users database
for password in range(len(Passwords)):
    if PasswordEntry.get() == password:
        # updates variable with username of current user
        UsernameofCurrentUser = UsernameEntered
        Screen4(UsernameofCurrentUser)
        Screen3.destroy()
    else:
        # displays an error message if the password the user enters is not in the Users database
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("","Your password has not been recognised, please try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not how SQL should be used *at all* . You do not populate Python list with all entries from SQL.

Instead you select from SQL only the data that matches the Username and password given by user trying to login. If there is no match, it means the password was wrong or user doesn't exist. See application of WHERE clause in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)

I am sorry but your question means you need to learn how to work with SQL first.

--

According to your request, here is the simplest way to check if supplied login and password match the ones stored in SQL. This is not something to put in a production system (for example, in production you should rather store passwords encrypted and encrypt submitted password for checking against DB).

Note, that passing parameters from Python to SQL query might differ, depending on the SQL module you use. There are modules that bind parameters in named :arguments, and those that only allow to replace arguments with "?" signs and pass the arguments by position. Here we go with "?" and positional arguments given in a tuple.

```
def UserDetailsValidator(login,password):
    c.execute("SELECT userdetails FROM tblUserDetails WHERE username=? AND userpass=?", (login,password))
    results=c.fetchall()
    if len(results)>1:
        print "Error. More than one login with this password found in database"
        return
    elif len(results)<1:
        print "Wrong username or password entered"
        return
    # else found exactly 1 result with that username & pass combo, 
    # meaning that user supplied the correct pass
    userinfo=results[0]
    # there is just 1 row returned from SQL, which contains the userinfo we want.
    # can work with that now.
```

Comment: Can you code an example demonstrating how I would go about doing that. I have tried to but I'm not quite sure about what to do.

Comment: @user9156115 added a very basic example.

Comment: Thank you.  What does fetchall() do?

Comment: @user9156115  fetches all result rows into a list.